# Generating all possible paths through a tree

Tags: python, algorithm, tree

I need to generate all possible paths through a tree where child-nodes are shared by adjacent parents. The tree looks like this :

#### Two tree-examples:

[image: Two Trees]

For a tree of size 3 the traversal would look like this:
[image]

The expected output for the size 3 tree would be this:

```
[0,0,0]
[0,0,1]
[0,1,1]
[0,1,2]
```

So the topmost node is the 0-th index and the bottom most nodes are the n-th index. The value represents which node at the respective level is traversed.

Now I need to generate all possible paths from top to bottom of a tree for arbitrary sizes of trees.

I have tried something like this but to no avail.

```
test = [0,0,0,0,0]
count = 0

while test[0]<5:
    for i in range(count):
        test[i] += 1
    count += 1
    print(test)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @Sazzy ...that is not at all the same type of counter.

Comment: @Sazzy Yes, I have seen that. Unfortunately, that isn't what I wanted.

Comment: we need more lines of output. logic behind your desired result is not clear

Comment: Can you explain the logic of the "counting"? Why does `[1,1,0,0]` turn into `[2,1,0,0]` and then `[1,1,1,0]`?

Comment: think in terms of transition: what are the rules to go from one line to the next? Also, what do you mean by "expandable"? Can the list of terms (on each line) grow?

Comment: I've edited it to include a better description of it "counting". Hope it helps understanding what I'm trying to do. But now the question is closed?

Comment: I edited the question and reworded it to make clear and obvious, what the expected output is. I also directly included the images which add a lot towards understanding the what is asked. In my opinion its now very understandable and should be reopened.

Comment: Thank you! I'm totally new to this website and coding, so the help is greatly appreciated! I think it makes a lot of sense too, now :)

Comment: So how do I get the question reopened?

Comment: I alreay flagged the question for moderator attention. You could do the same.

Comment: I know you might have found a solution, but adding it to the question body is not allowed. You need to get the question reopened to be able to provide the solution. Usually, the process would be that after your edits the question goes into review and users decide if they want to reopen it. If this will not yield good results you might try asking on Meta after a couple of days for a broader community review of your improved question.

Comment: Wait, what, why? I can't add my solution to my own question? If someone finds this and has the same problem, they should just be left in the dark? What kind of weird rules does this site have?

Comment: @peterlravn, actually [you're welcome to answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). But you still need to follow the question-and-answer format. Answers don't belong as part of your _question_. To self-answer, you need to write an answer in the _answer_ section below. That currently isn't possible since this question is closed.

Comment: @peterlravn, you have improved this question, but I'm still confused about what you're asking. Where do the `2` and `3`s come from in your tree examples? Normally for a binary tree you'd only ever have `0`s (for left) and `1`s (for right), or vice-versa. For this reason I am not currently going to vote to reopen, but if you further clarify it I might be willing to vote to reopen.

Comment: And why does each path in your "tree of size 3" example have _three_ numbers? There are only two decisions to traverse that tree: (1) Do I go left or right from the root node? and then (2) Do I go left or right to a leaf node? The expected answers should be `0,0`, `0,1`, `1,0`, `1,1`.

Comment: So you got to image the "tree" kind of laying down. It's easier to visualize when you stretch it like this:
https://imgur.com/a/pscFfyI
The path on the left reaches node 3 and can't go any further. Then it backs up, takes another branch and keeps walking.

Comment: @Chris 1. It is not a binary tree, that's why there are `2`s and `3`s come from. And 2. The its not the decisions that are in the example but the nodes, including the root-node.
But I am glad, that the answer is reopened so I can post my answer as well. Sometimes the heavy system of democracy just needs some time I guess.

Comment: Yes, finally someone who understand what I'm trying to draw up. Thought I was being crazy. I'll post my own solution as a reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my answer to the problem:

```
def mutate(array, depth):
    new_array = []
    for path in array:
        new_array.append(path+[path[-1]])
        new_array.append(path+[path[-1]+1])
    if(depth > 2):
        return mutate(new_array, depth-1)
    else:
        return new_array

print(mutate([[0]],5))

mutate([0],1)
```

It is a recursive function with computational-complecity of `O(N^2)`

Essentially the function adds one layer for each recursion.
For each path in a n-tree there are two paths in a n+1-tree. One with the same node-index in the n+1-layer and one with the node-index incremented by one.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**
Check the following code:

```
from copy import copy 

h = 2
current_h = 0
possible_paths = list()
possible_paths.append([0])
while current_h < h:
    new_paths = []
    for item in possible_paths:
        pow_res = pow(2,item[len(item)-1])
        item1 = copy(item)
        item2 = copy(item)
        item1.append(pow_res-1)
        item2.append(pow_res)
        new_paths.append(item1)
        new_paths.append(item2)
    possible_paths = new_paths
    current_h = current_h + 1

print(possible_paths)
```

Comment: I've updated the code, I was thinking exactly opposite :d.

Comment: Well that's still not the expected output... Are you running your code? The expected output is right there in the question...

Comment: I've updated the question. Does it make it any clearer?

Comment: check out the updated code. it might works.

Comment: Hey, it doesn't work fully, as seen here: https://imgur.com/a/wbr2ynh
I've modified it in the second picture, and it basically does what I want except it's reversed. I dont know what's goin on. Here my code:

Comment: from copy import copy 

    h = 4
    current_h = 0
    possible_paths = list()
    possible_paths.append([0])
    while current_h < h:
        new_paths = []
        for item in possible_paths:
            pow_res = item[len(item)-1]
            item1 = copy(item)
            item2 = copy(item)
            item1.append(pow_res-1)
            item2.append(pow_res)
            new_paths.append(item1)
            new_paths.append(item2)
        possible_paths = new_paths
        current_h = current_h + 1

    possible_paths

Comment: I don't know how to make code in comments

Comment: you have removed the "pow" function from my code actually. that's why it's not working properly.

Comment: Yes, I removed it on purpose. If I keep it and set h=4, i get this:
https://imgur.com/a/gObBxYV
Anything else I need to change besides the value of h?

Comment: I've updated the main post with a working code! Thank you very much!

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided. See [answer].

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Sorosh I modified their code to this:

```
 from copy import copy 

h = 5
current_h = 0
possible_paths = list()
possible_paths.append([0])
while current_h < h-1:
    new_paths = []
    for item in possible_paths:
        pow_res = item[current_h]
        item1 = copy(item)
        item2 = copy(item)
        item1.append(pow_res)
        item2.append(pow_res+1)
        new_paths.append(item1)
        new_paths.append(item2)
    possible_paths = new_paths
    current_h = current_h + 1

possible_paths
```

This gives the output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 2],
 [0, 0, 1, 2, 2],
 [0, 0, 1, 2, 3],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 2],
 [0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
 [0, 1, 1, 2, 3],
 [0, 1, 2, 2, 2],
 [0, 1, 2, 2, 3],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 3],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

One just needs to change the value of h. Right now, it goes through a whole tree with 5 'nodes' down.

I'm not entirely sure why this works though.